# Error with float values, iterables, and matrices

Tags: python

I apologize in advance if this is a poor question / has already been answered.

Here's a snippet of a program I'm trying to write that works with a matrix. I want it to take the columns, then add its contents to col[x].

```
col = []
for x in range(len(matrix[0])):
    col.append([float(0)])

for x in range(len(matrix[0])):
    for y in range(len(matrix)):
        matrix[x][y] = float(matrix[x][y])

for x in range(len(matrix[0])):
    for y in range(len(matrix)):
        col[x] += matrix[x][y]
```

When I run the program, the error message reads "'float' object is not iterable" for the last line. Why can't I just "+=" two float values using two separate lists?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the way you set up you `col` variable.

As it is:

```
col = []
for x in range(len(matrix[0])):
    col.append([float(0)])
```

the `col` is rendered as a `list` of `list` of 1 element:

```
>>> col
[[0.0], [0.0], [0.0]]
```

Therefore, you cannot say `col[x] += 2.0` in the last loop, because it tries to add a `float` to a `list`.

Define `col` like :

```
col = []
for x in range(len(matrix[0])):
    col.append(float(0))
```

which will create a `list` of `float`

```
>>> col
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

and will render `col[x] += 2.0` a valid instruction.

Comment: I love looking back at this years later and seeing such a well-constructed answer. Thank you, M'vy!

Comment: My pleasure ;) Pretty sure this could use some updating, like creating the list using the `list()` constructor.